# How to point http to https subdomain in NGINX?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

I am working on a Spring Boot app that servers content for 3 types of users. All three users "live" in the same application. I want to configure NGINX to 1) redirect all http to https and 2) redirect traffic as follows:

http to https://www.example.com

http://b2b.example.com to https://b2b.example.com/b2b (Ideally not showing the "/b2b". Here all the b2b spring boot endpoints are listening)

So far this is my NGINX conf:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    access_log ...;
    error_log ...;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # re-write redirects to http as to https, example: /home
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name b2b.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    access_log ...;
    error_log ...;
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/b2b;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # re-write redirects to http as to https, example: /home
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    }
}
```

On Sring Boot side, all B2B endpoints are listening to a pattern starting with "B2B". So for example the login page for these users is .../B2B/login. Right now if I go to b2b.example.com I get redirected to b2b.example.com/B2B/login. What I want is the browser to show "B2B.example.com/login" and to display the "/B2B/login" page. All the B2B sites omitting the "/B2B" part in the URL.

Comment: You don't say what the problem with the existing configuration is. But one observation is that the `proxy_pass` should have a trailing `/`, for example: `proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/b2b/;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my original post to make it more descriptive.

Comment: Use `curl -I` to identify the value of the `Location` response header. You will need to change the `proxy_redirect` statement to match the response in order to correct it.

Comment: if I do curl -I b2b.example.com as a response header I get "https://b2b.nwblty.com/
To be honest I don't really understand how to change the proxy_redirect